# listdata.svc total number of records in Sharepoint folder

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2010, ios7, filter

I am implementing an iOS app using Sharepoint 2010 and accessing using REST api. I see there is some Sharepoint threshold and I am able to receive 1000 records at time from client application. How can I write a oData Query to find total number of records in a given folder?

```
listdata.svc/SPLibrary()?$filter=substringof('ABC',Path)
```

This api giving me 1000 records from ABC folder where ABC has 2000 entities/records. How to find number of records in this ABC folder so that I can get metadata again?

Comment: I guess $count  would do the job.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2011/04/21/counting-entities-in-an-odata-service.aspx